# What does it mean to "Pump GTK messages?"

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, pygame

**Intro**

I am new to GTK+ programming and am having difficulty understanding why the following does not block.

```
if self.journal:
    # Pump GTK messages.
    while gtk.events_pending(): gtk.main_iteration()
```

According to the PyGtk reference on `gtk.main_iteration()`, the default value for `block` is `True`, which should, seemingly, prevent the local code from running until events have been processed.

Yet, I don't see this happening.  Perhaps, a clue is in the `# Pump GTK messages.` comment.  But I don't understand what the comment is trying to convey to me.

**My Question**

So, my question is ***What does it mean to "Pump GTK messages?"***  Please be as low-level as possible.  I understand that GTK is my widget toolkit and is designed to handle events.

**Background**

I am following a Sugar tutorial at [flossmanuals](http://en.flossmanuals.net/make-your-own-sugar-activities/) using the [SimCom](http://activities.sugarlabs.org/en-US/sugar/addon/4472) activity.  This is the section of code (to provide context) from which the snippet above is pulled.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# SimCom.py
"""
    Copyright (C) 2011  Peter Hewitt

    This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
    the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
    (at your option) any later version.

"""
import g,pygame,utils,sys,buttons,slider,load_save
try:
    import gtk
except:
    pass
import sim

class SimCom:

    def __init__(self):
        self.journal=True # set to False if we come in via main()
        self.canvas=None # set to the pygame canvas if we come in via activity.py
.
.
.

    def run(self):
        g.init()
        if not self.journal: utils.load()
        self.sim=sim.Sim()
        load_save.retrieve()
        self.buttons_setup()
        if g.saved_n==0: buttons.off('cyan')
        self.slider=slider.Slider(g.sx(23.4),g.sy(20.2),5,utils.GREEN)
        if self.canvas<>None: self.canvas.grab_focus()
        ctrl=False
        pygame.key.set_repeat(600,120); key_ms=pygame.time.get_ticks()
        going=True
        while going:
            if self.journal:
                # Pump GTK messages.
                while gtk.events_pending(): gtk.main_iteration()

            # Pump PyGame messages.
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                    if not self.journal: utils.save()
                    going=False
                elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
                    g.pos=event.pos
                    g.redraw=True
                    if self.canvas<>None: self.canvas.grab_focus()
                elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    g.redraw=True
                    if g.help_on: g.help_on=False 
                    elif event.button==1:
                        if self.do_click():
                            pass
                        elif self.slider.mouse():
                            pass # level changed
                        else:
                            bu=buttons.check()
                            if bu!='': self.do_button(bu); self.flush_queue()
                    elif event.button==3:
                        self.right_click()
                elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    # throttle keyboard repeat
                    if pygame.time.get_ticks()-key_ms>110:
                        key_ms=pygame.time.get_ticks()
                        if ctrl:
                            if event.key==pygame.K_q:
                                if not self.journal: utils.save()
                                going=False; break
                            else:
                                ctrl=False
                        if event.key in (pygame.K_LCTRL,pygame.K_RCTRL):
                            ctrl=True; break
                        self.do_key(event.key); g.redraw=True
                        self.flush_queue()
                elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                    ctrl=False
            if not going: break
            self.update()
            if g.redraw:
                self.display()
                if g.version_display: utils.version_display()
                g.screen.blit(g.pointer,g.pos)
                pygame.display.flip()
                g.redraw=False
            g.clock.tick(40)

if __name__=="__main__":
    pygame.init()
    pygame.display.set_mode()
    game=SimCom()
    game.journal=False
    game.run()
    pygame.display.quit()
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit(0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> According to the PyGtk reference on gtk.main_iteration(), the default value for block is True, 
>   which should, seemingly, prevent the local code from running until events have been processed.

Right, But the code:

```
while gtk.events_pending(): gtk.main_iteration()
```

first checks if there are any events, and only runs `gtk.main_iteration()` if there are. So there's always at least one event to process, which means it will never block.

gtk.main_iteration() does one iteration of the gtk main loop, which will process and handle the pending events (mouse events, screen redraw requests, key input, audio input/output, whatever gtk needs to do to drive the UI and handle requests from the operating system/graphics interface(The X11 server in case of *nix)). Often such events results in dispatching callbacks that you, or a library like pygame, have registred.

Comment: Eureka!  Beautifully explained.  Thank YOU!

Comment: So, effectively, "Pump GTK messages" means to call (if there are events pending in the queue) the `gtk main loop` and process all `events` which have been received from the system.  So a `message` is an event which has been received from the underlying system -- and has been queued??

Comment: Yes, though your code (or pygame) could queue events internally as well, e.g. a request to resize the screen. The system events are typically not already received, as that's impossible since your code is running, not the gtk code that receives the events. So that's what the gtk main loop does, receives and process such events.